# The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a get request, however I am getting the error:

> The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property
>   or method. 
>       Parameter name: name

I have looked about but cannot seem to find anything at all, this is the code that I have.

```css
HttpWebRequest request=(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(--URL--);
request.Method="GET";
WebHeaderCollection headers=new WebHeaderCollection();
request.ContentType="application/json; charset=utf-8";
headers.Add("Client-ID", --ID--);
headers["Accept"]="application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json";
//headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json");
request.Headers=headers;
using (HttpWebResponse response=(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
  Stream dataStream=response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(dataStream);
  string output=reader.ReadToEnd();
  MessageBox.Show(output);
  reader.Close();
  dataStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json");

Comment: I tried that however im still getting the same error.